# Power Query - Cumulative Counter (index) for specific text

Tags: excel, powerquery

In Excel's powerquery editor I have two columns. Both have random strings in there. 
See this image:

[image]

I want to replace all values of a particular string, in this case: 'a' with a running counter. The other values should be replaced with 'null'. The end result should be the following image:

[image]

Specific rule:

- The code needs to be general; the amount of columns and rows will vary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will work for any number of colums and rows.

```
let Filter="a",
Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
Columns = Table.ColumnNames(Source),
#"Added Index1" = Table.AddIndexColumn(Source, "Indexz", 0, 1),
Unpivot = Table.UnpivotOtherColumns(#"Added Index1", {"Indexz"}, "Attribute", "Value"),
Grouped = Table.Group(Unpivot, {"Attribute","Value"}, {{"Count", each Table.AddIndexColumn(_, "Index",1,1), type table}}),
#"Expanded Count" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(Grouped, "Count", {"Indexz", "Index"}, {"Indexz", "Index"}),
#"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Expanded Count", "Count", each if [Value]=Filter then [Index] else null),
#"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Added Custom",{"Value","Index"}),
#"Pivoted Column" = Table.Pivot(#"Removed Columns", List.Distinct(#"Removed Columns"[Attribute]), "Attribute", "Count"),
#"Removed Columns1" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Pivoted Column",{"Indexz"})
in #"Removed Columns1"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by creating a partition for each value per column, and adding an index within the partition. Repeat for both columns, then replace values with the index, when the criteria matches:

```
let
    Source = MySource,
    Criteria = "a",
    #"Added Index" = Table.AddIndexColumn(Source, "SortIndex", 1, 1),
    #"Partition 2" = Table.Group(#"Added Index", {"column 2"}, {{"Partition", each Table.AddIndexColumn(_, "Index",1,1), type table}}),
    #"Expanded Partition 2" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Partition 2", "Partition", {"column 1", "SortIndex", "Index"}, {"column 1", "SortIndex", "Index 2"}),
    #"Sort 2" = Table.Sort(#"Expanded Partition 2",{{"SortIndex", Order.Ascending}}),
    #"Partition 1" = Table.Group(#"Sort 2", {"column 1"}, {{"Partition", each Table.AddIndexColumn(_, "Index",1,1), type table}}),
    #"Expand Partition 1" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Partition 1", "Partition", {"column 2", "SortIndex", "Index 2", "Index"}, {"column 2", "SortIndex", "Index 2", "Index 1"}),
    #"Sort 1" = Table.Sort(#"Expand Partition 1",{{"SortIndex", Order.Ascending}}),
    #"Replaced 1" = Table.ReplaceValue(#"Sort 1",each [column 1], each if [column 1] = Criteria then [Index 1] else null, Replacer.ReplaceValue,{"column 1"}),
    #"Replaced 2" = Table.ReplaceValue(#"Replaced 1",each [column 2], each if [column 2] = Criteria then [Index 2] else null, Replacer.ReplaceValue,{"column 2"}),
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Replaced 2",{"SortIndex", "Index 2", "Index 1"})
in
    #"Removed Columns"
```